# How to append block string variable to file with bash script?

Tags: bash

I would like to append the following to my ~/.bash_profile:

```
# ---------------
# PERSONNAL EDITS

# anaconda3
. /opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

To do so, I use the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

app_str=\
'\n
# ---------------\n
# PERSONNAL EDITS\n
\n
# anaconda3\n
. /opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh'

echo -e $app_str >> ~/.bash_profile
```

However, the result is the following:

```
<lines above...>

 # ---------------
 # PERSONNAL EDITS 

 # anaconda3
 . /opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

---

There is a spacing in front of each line appended to the file. How do I remove the spacing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the variable:

```
echo -e "$app_str"
```

Reference : [When to quote a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, could you elaborate what the double quote does?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using a *here document* instead:

```
cat >> ~/.bash_profile <<'EOF'    
# ---------------
# PERSONNAL EDITS

# anaconda3
. /opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
EOF
```

IMHO it's easier to read and more maintainable than trying to echo a multiline string.